# Controlling order of unit test methods in OCUnit

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testcase, ocunit

I have been using OCUnit for unit testing in a project. I've managed to do all the setup required for OCUnit in Xcode 4.2 & successfully build my test cases.

How can I control the order (priority) for a test case? I see that test cases are built in alphabetic order of their name, i.e. if I have test method `testA, testB, testC`, they'll be executed in that same order.

What I need is for "testC" in the above example to be executed *before* "testB", as my method has some setup for variables & preferences for "testB", as well as core data entry, included in "testC".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either your make your test cases self-contained, so that they can run on their own without pre-conditions, or you name your test methods accordingly as you mentioned.

```
test0First, test1Second
```

I would recommend to make them self-contained. It's a little overhead, but you can implement reusable methods in your test case (that don't start with `test`) to make your life easier.

If you want a framework with more features check out [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit)

Comment: Isnt there any other way out because i cant make all of my test cases atomic

Comment: You can do it, you can make each test self-contained. It may take some pain to get there - for example, adding extra seams so that you redirect your writes to a fake data store - but this is a must-fix.